# Use Linq Select to display data

Tags: c#, linq

I have this code to display the content  of a `List<int>` within a console.

```
List<int> mylist = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
mylist.Select(i => { Console.WriteLine(i); return false; });
```

But it doesn't show anything. Is there a way to make this producing a output without using `.ForEach()` ?

Comment: no need to downvote if you have suggestion you can improve answer with edit

Answer (score 0):

`Select` is used to manipulate your enumerable. If you want to do some action go with a `foreach` or join the data to a string like that:

```
Console.WriteLine(String.Join("\r\n", myList));
```

`String.Join(separator, collection)` will join your collection to a string by the given separator.

Alternatively:

```
myList.ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine(x));
```

According the comments:

[image]

Check out `newList`. The selected elements of the `select` will be stored. In this case the action to print something is stored. If you call it (first red block) it will get executed.

That's why it is called `select` and not `execute`. It is *selecting* something into a new variable. Notice that returning 3 also gets stored and "executed" on call.

Comment: But _why_ doesn't Select print the output?

Comment: @MetaColon Check my edit.

Comment: Fascinating behaviour. Thanks for that information.

Answer (score 0):

The execution of LINQ extensions are deferred until you start consuming the result. This is the reason why the results are not shown in console. Following code is precisely what you have mentioned in your thread and I added `ToList()` which start consuming the result.

```
List<int> mylist = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
mylist.Select(i => { Console.WriteLine(i); return false; }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Linq uses defered execution; the result is not computed until it is required.

You never use the result of the `Select`; so it is not performed.

Try this

```
mylist
  .Select(i => { Console.WriteLine(i); return false; })
  .Count();
```

Comment: I replaced `Select` with `Any` from duplicate mark